# Relationship between the standard error of the estimators and the standard error of the error term

Tags: statistics, regression, standard-deviation, linear-regression

I'm trying to solve the following problem:
[image: equation]

[image: question]

---

My thinking is that If the Standard error of the error term would then the error term of the regression would also fall (as the regression would start performing better).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, e.g., for the slope
$$
Var(\hat{\beta}_1) =\frac{1}{(\sum(x_i - \bar{x})^2)^2}Var\left( \sum (x_i - \bar{x})y_i \right) = \frac{\sigma^2}{\sum(x_i - \bar{x})^2},
$$
where $Var(\epsilon_i) = \sigma^2$. For the intercept you have 
$$
Var(\hat{\beta}_0) =\frac{\sigma^2}{n} + \frac{\sigma^2\bar{x}^2}{\sum(x_i - \bar{x})^2},
$$
thus reducing the variance of $\epsilon_i$ will reduce the standard error of the OLS estimators.